# Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to display a total and occupation code as columns and the count of dcode inside the rows but it gives me an error:

> Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the
>   group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

```
select count(*) as total

,(select count(dcode) from c122117a_A I where I.dcode = o.dcode and occupation='49' and left(zip,3) between '900' and '934') as 'Doctors-49'

,(select count(dcode) from c122117a_A I where I.dcode = o.dcode and occupation='17' and left(zip,3) between '900' and '934') as 'Health Services-17'

,(select count(dcode) from c122117a_A I where I.dcode = o.dcode and occupation='53' and left(zip,3) between '900' and '934') as '53=Insurance/Underwriters'

,(select count(dcode) from c122117a_A I where I.dcode = o.dcode and occupation='41' and left(zip,3) between '900' and '934') as '41=Occupational Therapy' 

,(select count(dcode) from c122117a_A I where I.dcode = o.dcode and occupation='48' and left(zip,3) between '900' and '934') as '48=Nurses'

,(select count(dcode) from c122117a_A I where I.dcode = o.dcode and occupation='43' and left(zip,3) between '900' and '934') as '43=Psychologists'

,(select count(dcode) from c122117a_A I where I.dcode = o.dcode and occupation='21' and left(zip,3) between '900' and '934') as '21=Teacher/Educator'

from c122117a_A o
group by count(*) 
order by count(*)
```

Comment: What that not very intuitive error is trying to say is: how are you going to have a subquery where you join the dcode to the outer table "o" when dcode is being grouped in the outer query?

Comment: The error message is straightforward. Remove `group by count(*)`.

Comment: What are you trying to group by? You don't need all those sub queries either. You just need to aggregate on CASE expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, complete omitted columns

```
select count(o.dcode) as total
,sum(case when occupation='49' and left(zip,3) between '900' and '934' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Doctors-49'
,sum(case when occupation='17' and left(zip,3) between '900' and '934' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Health Services-17'
...
from c122117a_A o
group by o.dcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `group by count(*)` with `group by dcode`. Because you refer to o.dcode in your subqueries, you have to specify which one. And if you don't group by them, all dcodes are taken together and the database can't determine which one (value) to use.